# PHP Including JS table not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have a user page in which I include several tables, one of which uses a pagination script that is handled by javascript (so that I dont have to refresh the page when looking through the pages) now I'm trying to include this on my user.php page but it doesnt seem to work, any help appreciated

User.php page

```html
<?php require 'session.php';
require 'header.php';
require 'includes/database.php';
    $userid = $_GET['id'];
$con = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
  if(!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db($dbname);
//CLIENT INFO TABLE
include 'user/clientinfo.php';

echo "<br>";

// XLRSTATS TABLE
include 'user/xlrstatsinfo.php';

echo "<br>";

//ALIAS TABLE
include 'user/aliases.php';

//IP TABLE
include 'user/ipaliases.php';

//PENALTY TABLE
include 'user/penalties.php';

//PENALTY TABLE
include 'user/userchatlog.php';

?>
```

userchatlog.php page

```html
<?php
require '../session.php';
?>
<div id='retrieved-data'>
 <!-- 
 this is where data will be  shown
 -->
    <img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://144.76.158.173/ech/includes/css/main.css" />
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "../includes/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function() {
 //call the function onload
 getdata( 1 );
});

function getdata( pageno ){                     
 var targetURL = '../includes/pagination/userchatlog/search_results.php?page=' + pageno;   

 $('#retrieved-data').html('<p><img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" /></p>');        
 $('#retrieved-data').load( targetURL ).hide().fadeIn('slow');
}      
</script>
```

and my search_results.php

```html
<!-- include style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://144.76.158.173/ech/includes/css/main.css" />
<?php
//open database
include '../../database.php';
//include our awesome pagination
//class (library)
include 'ps_pagination.php';

//connect to mysql server
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//check if any connection error was encountered
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";
    exit;
}
function _ago($tm,$rcs = 0) {
   $cur_tm = time(); $dif = $cur_tm-$tm;
   $pds = array('second','minute','hour','day','week','month','year','decade');
   $lngh = array(1,60,3600,86400,604800,2630880,31570560,315705600);
   for($v = sizeof($lngh)-1; ($v >= 0)&&(($no = $dif/$lngh[$v])<=1); $v--); if($v < 0) $v = 0; $_tm = $cur_tm-($dif%$lngh[$v]);

   $no = floor($no); if($no <> 1) $pds[$v] .='s ago'; $x=sprintf("%d %s ",$no,$pds[$v]);
   if(($rcs == 1)&&($v >= 1)&&(($cur_tm-$_tm) > 0)) $x .= time_ago($_tm);
   return $x;
}
//query all data anyway you want
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chatlog WHERE msg NOT LIKE '%RADIO%' ORDER BY id DESC";

//now, where gonna use our pagination class
//this is a significant part of our pagination
//i will explain the PS_Pagination parameters
//$conn is a variable from our config_open_db.php
//$sql is our sql statement above
//3 is the number of records retrieved per page
//4 is the number of page numbers rendered below
//null - i used null since in dont have any other
//parameters to pass (i.e. param1=valu1&param2=value2)
//you can use this if you're gonna use this class for search
//results since you will have to pass search keywords
$pager = new PS_Pagination( $mysqli, $sql, 45, 4, null );

//our pagination class will render new
//recordset (search results now are limited
//for pagination)

$rs = $pager->paginate(); 

//get retrieved rows to check if
//there are retrieved data
$num = $rs->num_rows;

if($num >= 1 ){
 //creating our table header
 echo "<table id='my-tbl'>";
 echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th>Time</th>";
  echo "<th>Name</th>";
  echo "<th>Message</th>";
 echo "</tr>";
 
 //looping through the records retrieved
 while( $row = $rs->fetch_assoc() ){
$msg=$row['msg'];
$team=$row['client_team'];
$team = str_replace("42","<img src=images/green.png>",$team);
$team = str_replace("3","<img src=images/red.png>",$team);
$team = str_replace("2","<img src=images/blue.png>",$team);
$team = str_replace("1","<img src=images/grey.png>",$team);
$msg = str_replace("^0","</font><font color=black>",$msg);
$msg = str_replace("^1","</font><font color=red>",$msg);
$msg = str_replace("^2","</font><font color=lime>",$msg);
$msg = str_replace("^3","</font><font color=yellow>",$msg);
$msg = str_replace("^4","</font><font color=blue>",$msg);
$msg = str_replace("^5","</font><font color=aqua>",$msg);
$msg = str_replace("^6","</font><font color=#FF00FF>",$msg);
$msg = str_replace("^7","</font><font color=white>",$msg);
$msg = str_replace("^8","</font><font color=white>",$msg);
$msg = str_replace("^9","</font><font color=gray>",$msg);
$name=$row['client_name'];
$name=htmlentities($name);
$time=$row['msg_time'];
  echo "<tr class='data-tr' align='center'>";
 echo "<td align=center>";
 echo _ago($time);
 echo "</td>";
 echo "<td align=center>";
 echo $team;
 echo "<a href='http://144.76.158.173/ech/user.php?id=".$row["client_id"]."' > $name </a></td>";
 echo "<td align=left> $msg </td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }       
 
 echo "</table>";
}else{
 //if no records found
 echo "No records found!";
}
//page-nav class to control
//the appearance of our page 
//number navigation
echo "<div class='page-nav' align='center'>";
 //display our page number navigation
 echo $pager->renderFullNav();
echo "</div>";

?>
```

Comment: Hmm, do you see an error ?

Comment: No I don't see any error, I see nothing at all